# How do I display results from a database into an input area?

Tags: php, variables, syntax, echo

```
            <?php
                $i = 0;
                while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
                    $i++;
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td><input value='{$row['moduleCode']}' />  </td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
```

As you can see in my php code i have tried echoing the results from the database into the input area via the 'value', however this keeps coming up with a syntax error? can someone show me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quoted strings if you want variables to be parsed within :

```
echo "<td><input value='{$row['moduleCode']}' />  </td>";
```

or extract your variables :

```
echo '<td><input value="'.$row['moduleCode'].'" />  </td>';
```